# visual studio code will show images in live server but when I open directly into browser no images

Tags: html, css, background

I'm using visual Studio Code and using live Server to see what it looks like as I'm coding.

Here's the dilemma I'm having. After coding it looks great on live server.

But when I open it directly into a browser (I've opened in chrome, firefox and explorer), everything works except the images doesn't show. (my background image, logo, icons, pictures will not display).
I transfer all files to my other laptop and same result

All my images are in CSS using the background attribute. Everything else works, font color, shadow, border, hover etc. except the images wont display (except in live server). Has anyone else have this issue and if so, how did you resolve it?

I've attached a screen capture of my code...I commented out all information in body. commented out the other css file and commented out all css code except for body tag, should work, but still will not show the body image. the picture file is located in the same location as the html file. I've used quotes and without quotes around the url address and same results.

I used my other laptop and coded the same thing on that (except using different image) the image worked on that one.(used visual studio code on that laptop as well)

I'm at a lost as to why this is happening. any help is appreciated. as I really dont want to have to re-write the html and css again.

[html and css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVqNp.png)

Comment: Stupid question, but needs asking... have you put `aluminum.png` on the server in the same directory as your CSS file? (Remember, url paths in CSS files are relative to the position of the CSS file itself.  It a common mistake to move CSS from the page itself into a CSS file, move that CSS file into a sub-directory and forget to update the url)

Comment: that solved the problem. I thought all paths was from the html and didnt occur that it was from the css location. once I updated by add up one folder, that solved the issue. Thanks again

Comment: As I say, a common mistake. You're not the first, you're definitely not going to be the last :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does your Webserver have the permission to view the image?

The way you wrote your css implies that the image is in the same folder as your .css file.

If it is not so do it like "../path/to/file.jpg"

Comment: I have not actually put anything online. the live server is just an extension for the visual studio code. all my codes and images are on my pc.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows OS? 

Paths on Windows need to be written with backslashs instead of normal slashs.